# Hubspot API Sorting Results Returned

Tags: postman, hubspot, hubspot-api

URL = `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/companies?limit=1&properties=abbreviated_name,name,industry&updatedAt=descending`

Results:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "abc123",
            "properties": {
                "abbreviated_name": null,
                "createdate": "2017-03-08T01:11:17.770Z",
                "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2024-02-21T17:52:18.510Z",
                "hs_object_id": "777",
                "industry": "INSURANCE",
                "name": "Example Insurance Co"
            },
            "createdAt": "2017-03-08T01:11:17.770Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-02-21T17:52:18.510Z",
            "archived": false
        },
        {
            "id": "xyz456",
            "properties": {
                "abbreviated_name": null,
                "createdate": "2017-03-08T16:14:34.689Z",
                "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2024-03-12T19:04:10.959Z",
                "hs_object_id": "888",
                "industry": "Technology",
                "name": "Example Technology Co"
            },
            "createdAt": "2017-03-08T16:14:34.689Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-03-12T19:04:10.959Z",
            "archived": false
        },
    ],
    "paging": {
        "next": {
            "after": "abc111",
            "link": "https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/companies?limit=2&properties=abbreviated_name%2Cname%2Cindustry&updatedAt=descending&after=abc111"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I need to do to modify the URL in Postman? It gives me the same values no matter what I put in for the `updatedAt` value? I am trying to sort by most recently updated.